# antD model API - Background colour change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is there a way to change the antD model body color using styles API? As per the documentation, model attributes can be changed using the styles attribute but the below code is changing only the footer background color.Any help would be really appreciated.

```
                   import { notification, Modal, Form, AutoComplete } from 'antd';
                   <Modal
                    mask={false}
                    title="Select Delivery Location"
                    style={{
                        top: 150,
                        // borderColor: '#00FF00', //changing the footer colour only
                        // backgroundColor: '#FF0000', //not working
                    }}
                    width={350}
                    onOk={this.handleOnModelSubmit}
                    visible={this.state.modal1Visible}
                    onCancel={() => this.setModal1Visible(false)}>

                    </Modal>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<Modal
    bodyStyle={{
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }}
/>
```

Either using 1 bracket '{' or 2 '{{'

Comment: Thanks. This is changing the body colour. Is there a way to change the header and footer colour of the model?

Comment: .ant-modal-footer {
    background-color: pink;
} override the css. Add !important if neccessary, so background-color: pink !important;. For header you can use .ant-modal-header. Just inspect the element, search for classname, then override it